# brew doctor throwing loads of errors?

Tags: laravel, homebrew, mcrypt

I recently installed Laravel on my Mac to begin learning about it as I've heard good things.

My first error was while accessing `/public/`:

> Laravel requires the Mcrypt PHP extension.

I then installed *php54-mcrypt* and continued learning yesterday evening.

I then came home today from work, hit 'brew update' and then the same error appeared?

I then ran brew `install php54-mcrypt` to receive:

> Warning: php54-mcrypt-5.4.16 already installed

I then ran `brew doctor` to receive;

> Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories
>       ./configure scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
>       software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
>       compiling and linking.
>
> Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
>       Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
>       script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
>
> ```
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
> /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> '/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.16/mcrypt.so' - 
> dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.16/mcrypt.so, 9): 
> Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib
> Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.16/mcrypt.so
> Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
> '/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.16/mcrypt.so' - 
> dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.16/mcrypt.so, 9): 
> Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib
> Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.16/mcrypt.so
> Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
> '/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.16/mcrypt.so' - 
> dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.16/mcrypt.so, 9): 
> Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libmcrypt.4.4.8.dylib
> Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/php54-mcrypt/5.4.16/mcrypt.so
> Reason: image not found in Unknown on line 0
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stuff in /usr/local/Cellar was put there by MacPorts, an earlier package manager for mac. You probably want to remove that. https://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.macports.uninstalling.html